# Search for tags in a xml Document

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my xml document

```
<item>
    <timeslot>67363</timeslot>
    <object>8GRM1</object>
    <status>A</status>
    <expl/>
</item>
<item>
    <timeslot>67365</timeslot>
    <timeslot2>67366</timeslot2>
    <object>8TEC6</object>
    <status>p</status>
</item>
```

I want to search (using javascript ) if the  tag exists or not for any particular item .

Any help will be appreciated .. Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have tried using  getXMLvalue(x[i], "expl");where grtxmlvalue is function getXMLvalue (node,tagname) {
 var tagValue = "";

 // If tag exists
 if (node.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0]) {
  // If tag is not empty get the value
  if (node.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild) {
   tagValue = node.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
  } 
 }
  return tagValue;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using jQuery, you can do something like the following:

```
var xml = "<item><timeslot>67363</timeslot><object>8GRM1</object><status>A</status><expl/></item><item><timeslot>67365</timeslot><timeslot2>67366</timeslot2><object>8TEC6</object><status>p</status></item>";

var textInsideTimeslotTag = $(xml).find('timeslot').text();
```

Comment: actually the problem is i cannot keep the xml into a variable because i have to make changes in it ... i want to search the xml document node by node to see if that blank tag <expl/> exists or not .. The actual problem is that blank tag because it returns a blank value ..this is why i cannot find which items contain that tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you wish to do but with the slight change, the method would return null if the tag being searched is an empty tag. Also please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrtKY/2/)

```
function getXMLvalue (node,tagname) 
{ 
  var tagValue = ""; // If tag exists 
  if (node.getElementsByTagName(tagname).length > 0) 
  { // If tag is not empty get the value 
    if (node.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild != null) 
    { 
      tagValue = node.getElementsByTagName(tagname)[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
    }
    else
    {
      return null;            
    }
  } 
  return tagValue; 
}
```